# Why is my android studio setup stuck at Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.0.12)"

Tags: android, android-studio, download, android-download-manager

[image]

I am using Linux Mint 20 Beta. I have tried manually downloading the emulator from the given url from the "Show Details" terminal view of the process, and added it to the sdk and yet it prompts me to set up the sdk when I try to start the program. I have switched my Java Version from 11 to 8, still it is the same, please help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just let it download what it takes, then it will show you up "Android SDK is up to date.", takes a lot of time.

[image: done]

Comment: yes. one can also check network activity to make sure download is taking place